# Does python have a built in min-heap data structure?

Tags: python, heap

Does python have a built in min-heap data structure in 2.7.3?

I don't want to import code.

I want something like

```
myheap = minheap(key=lambda x: x[1])
myheap.add(obj)
o = myheap.pop()
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Not in built-ins, you'll have to use [`import heapq`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html).

Comment: Check out the [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) module in the standard library...

Answer (score 10):

Like everybody says, `heapq` is it -- but, as nobody's mentioned yet, it **doesn't** support a `key=`!  So you need to fall back to the good old DSU (decorate-sort-undecorate) idiom that `key=` uses internally wherever it's supported (alas not in `heapq`, except for the functions `nlargest` and `nsmallest` that don't really have much to do with the rest of the module).

So you can wrap `heapq` functionality, with the addition of a key, e.g in a class of your own:

```
import heapq

class MyHeap(object):
    def __init__(self, key, data=())
        self.key = key
        self.heap = [(self.key(d), d) for d in data]
        heapq.heapify(self.heap)

    def push(self, item):
        decorated = self.key(item), item
        heapq.heappush(self.heap, decorated)

    def pop(self):
        decorated = heapq.heappop(self.heap)
        return decorated[1]

    def pushpop(self, item):
        decorated = self.key(item), item
        dd = heapq.heappushpop(self.heap, decorated)
        return dd[1]

    def replace(self, item):
        decorated = self.key(item), item
        dd = heapq.heapreplace(self.heap, decorated)
        return dd[1]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.heap)
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html for the distinction between `pushpop` and `replace` (and the other auxiliary functions supplied by standard library module `heapq`).

Comment: In heapq, if you are putting in objects, how can u use a lambda to specify its key? Like heapq.heappush(Q, v, key=lambda x: f(x))

Comment: In `heapq` directly, you don't, as I explain right at the start of my answer!  In the `MyHeap` class above, you instantiate `h=MyHeap(func)`, then the feature extraction func is used throughout automatically.  If you want to use as `func` a `lambda`, Python's single worst feature, rather than the clean and speedy equivalent `operator.itemgetter(1)` (requires an `import operator` of course), I cannot, alas!, stop you (since Guido, uncharacteristically, walked back from his original design decision to eliminate the bedraggled `lambda` in Python 3, we're stuck with it since Python 4 at least:-).

Comment: @AlexMartelli the second example  in https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#basic-examples indicates how you could use tuples with heapq, the first element is assumed to be the key.

Comment: @ziddarth, sure, if the priority is NOT a function of the queued content, then a `key=` equivalent wouldn't help and manually using (key, content) tuple pretty much the only way to go. But, that's not germane to the original question on this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Python comes with [heapq](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html), which you don't have to *download*, but you still have to *import*.

Python has very little in the way of data structures you can use without using the `import` statement altogether. Do you really want your language to have its entire standard library loaded in memory and namespace for every project?

Comment: In heapq, if you are putting in objects, how can u use a lambda to specify its key? Like heapq.heappush(Q, v, key=lambda x: f(x))

Comment: @omega, you can't, as I said in my answer: `heapq` does not support `key=` (except for a couple of auxiliary functions that don't affect your Q).