# How to use lambdas in python heapq?

Tags: python, heap

In python heapq if you are putting in objects, how can u use a lambda to specify its key? Like `heapq.heappush(Q, v, key=lambda x: f(x))`.

Thanks

Comment: umm, wasn't this question already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28016978/1426065)?

Answer (score 7):

You can't. Or rather, you can't specify it as a lambda. You can however make a heap of tuples, `heapq.heappush(Q, (key(v), v))` and `heapq.heappop(Q)[1]`.

Comment: Note that if `v` has no order, `key(v)` must return a unique number. Because if two `key(v)` are equal, heapq will try to order `v` and it will crash. See [this example](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-k-sorted-lists/discuss/500972/Python-heapq-70-Runtime-98-Memory).

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017037/how-to-use-lambdas-in-python-heapq#comment106317464_28017065), I'd say that [U2EF1's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28017065/1121497) is valid if `f(v)` will always return unique values, or if `v` can be ordered (you could also setup ordering, like in [this example](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-k-sorted-lists/discuss/500972/Python-heapq-70-Runtime-98-Memory)).

I made [these classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60128041/1121497) to make it easier to use heapq, and to allow lambdas for sorting.

In general you could do add a unique number to overcome that limitation:

```
heapq.heappush(Q, create_item(v, f))
(key, v) = heapq.heappop()

# f is your desired function/lambda
# unique_value() generates a different value each time (e.g. a counter)
def create_item(v, f):
    key = (f(v), unique_value())
    return (key, v)
```

It's a shame there's no way to send a function to heapq... :/